# Как освободить память после удаления Activity?

Tags: android, java

Как освободить память после удаления Activity? Создал 3 активити с картинками.

1) при запуске первого объем доходит до 20мб, делаю finish(), запускаю 2 активити;
2) 2 активити - память 30мб, делаю finish(), запускаю 3 активити;
3) 3 активити - память 43мб, делаю finish(), запускаю 1 активити;
4) 1 активити - память 48мб.

Я как понял, память увеличивается из-за кеша картинок, как удалить активити и очистить ресурсы, я все понимаю, это сделанно, чтобы можно было быстро переходить с 1 активити на 2. Но если я запускаю 1 активити только один раз за весь цикл жизни проги, мне по-любому надо его полностью очистить, как сделать это?

Да, самое главное:

Image у меня штук по 10-20 в каждом активити, каждый recycle делать это очень гавнокодично будет...

Comment: Что за приложение такое пишете? Проблемы с тем, что GC не справляется с поставленной ему задачей, бывают обычно только у разработчиков читалок, которым нужно рендерить на перед несколько картинок, и у просмотрищиков фотографий (которые не додумались их ждать предварительно). В остальных случаях обычно всегда можно ужать картинку.

Comment: @KoVadim, если я буду переходить с 1 активити на 2, потом на 1, на 2, на 1, на 2, так раз 100, у меня память на 10 метров увеличивается. Лучше бы пользователь сам чистил память, так понятнее было, как в C++.

Comment: если после каждого перехода память только увеличивается, то это называется утечка памяти. И GC тут не поможет.

Ругаться не стоит. Мы же не на зоне.

Comment: @xTIGRx GC не "гавно тупое", он работает на много лучше, чем твой код. И он очистит память, как только ему это будет нужно. Исключение составляют memory leaks, которые создаются благодаря твоему г0вн0коду. Судя по вопросам, которые ты задаешь, проблема именно в твоем коде, а не в GC.

Comment: recycle() делать всегда правильно. Странно слышать это от человека который, апеллирует к C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то я писал андроид прогу (графический редактор), и была необходимость держать в памяти две картинки для для отмены-возврата действий. Короче говоря, при открытии новой картинки, память оказывалась забитой. Приходилось вызывать метод recycle для моих старых картинок. Вроде помогло. Единственное ограничение - это была куча (на каждом телефоне размер свой), следовательно пришлось ловить исключение нехватки памяти. Так что, если у тебя работа с БОЛЬШИМИ картинками, попробуй вызывать recycle. БОЛЬШИМИ я имею в виду разрешение около 1к * 1к.

P.S. Не помню, знатоки подскажите - команда GC обязует JVM выполнить сборщик мусора или это рекомендация на запуск сборщика (но не обязанность)?

Comment: jvm может смело игнорировать команды на уборку мусора.

Comment: Вообще System.GC() в Android вызывать смысла не имеет. Гораздо эффективнее использовать так называемые слабые ссылки (вкратце - объекты, на которые существуют только слабые ссылки, будут очищены при следующем вызове GC. Есть вариации слабых ссылок, которые очищаются при каждом GC, или только при pre-OutOfMemory GC)